# Connection strings in EntityFrameworkCore2.0 in a common class library

Tags: connection-string, entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0

I have an architecture that I need to provide access to many applications through a SQL Server database and I want to provide a .Net Standard 2.0 class library (to be compatible to .Net Framework 4.6+ and .Net Core 2.0+)  that has the models/dbcontext and the definition of a default name of environment variables for the database connection string.

The problem is that I didn't find a way to inject the dependency of DbContext in .Net Core applications, getting the connection from this class library.

I am currently replicating the dbcontext and environment variable reading for the connection string to each application (which is not what I want) as in the config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connString =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENV_CONNECTION_STRING"); 

    services.AddDbContext<ModelContextReplicated>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connString));
    ...
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Application with EF Core is web or console?

Comment: Both! The purpose is to have one WebApi application for general queries and many batch console applications having access to insertions directly in the database. PS.: I've updated my code to use environment variables to get the connection string as I need different envs for testings, dev, production, etc.